# Aggregate SCD Type 2 data "as of" each day

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, google-bigquery

### Problem

When working with SCD type 2 data it's easy to see the state of a table "as of" a given point in time by using your date columns, eg: `valid_from` and `valid_to`. For example:

```sql
select * from table
where '2023-11-01' between valid_from and valid_to
```

You can then group by or use window functions to aggregate.

But what if I want to do that repeatedly, for each date in a range (eg: daily)? I do not need to aggregate *across* these dates, just within each one.

### Example

Let's say I have a table that tracks the `quantity` of people for each `reservation_id`. Both the `quantity` of people and `reservation_status` can change over time, as tracked by the table. Each reservation is attached to an `event_id`. `event_date` is included to help limit scope if needed (see assumptions below).

| reservation_id | reservation_status | quantity | event_id | event_date | valid_from | valid_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | active | 4 | 100 | 2023-05-25 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-02 |
| 2 | active | 2 | 200 | 2024-01-07 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-03 |
| 3 | active | 7 | 100 | 2023-05-25 | 2023-01-02 | 9999-12-31 |
| 4 | active | 1 | 200 | 2024-01-07 | 2023-01-02 | 9999-12-31 |
| 1 | active | 5 | 100 | 2023-05-25 | 2023-01-03 | 9999-12-31 |
| 5 | active | 8 | 100 | 2023-05-25 | 2023-01-03 | 9999-12-31 |
| 2 | cancelled | 2 | 200 | 2024-01-07 | 2023-01-04 | 9999-12-31 |
| 6 | active | 3 | 100 | 2023-05-25 | 2023-01-06 | 9999-12-31 |

PostgreSQL since BigQuery is more difficult to test – [db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QiMoN7M9) / SQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Reservations (
  "reservation_id" INTEGER,
  "reservation_status" VARCHAR(9),
  "quantity" INTEGER,
  "event_id" INTEGER,
  "event_date" DATE,
  "valid_from" DATE,
  "valid_to" DATE
);

INSERT INTO Reservations
  ("reservation_id", "reservation_status", "quantity", "event_id", "event_date", "valid_from", "valid_to")
VALUES
  ('1', 'active', '4', '100', '2023-05-25', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-02'),
  ('2', 'active', '2', '200', '2024-01-07', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-03'),
  ('3', 'active', '7', '100', '2023-05-25', '2023-01-02', '9999-12-31'),
  ('4', 'active', '1', '200', '2024-01-07', '2023-01-02', '9999-12-31'),
  ('1', 'active', '5', '100', '2023-05-25', '2023-01-03', '9999-12-31'),
  ('5', 'active', '8', '100', '2023-05-25', '2023-01-03', '9999-12-31'),
  ('2', 'cancelled', '2', '200', '2024-01-07', '2023-01-04', '9999-12-31'),
  ('6', 'active', '3', '100', '2023-05-25', '2023-01-06', '9999-12-31');
```

While this is ultimately for BigQuery, answer will be accepted in any dialect as long as it's somewhat generic.

###### Assumptions

- "As of" dates can be a list or range based off `valid_from` min/max
- `valid_to` of `9999-12-31` is the most recent data
- All reservations for a given event will be between `event_date - INTERVAL '2 years'` and `event_date`. This doesn't change anything for this example, but maybe is useful for scaling(?)

#### Desired output

I'd like to know the sum of `quantity` grouped by `event_id` and `reservation_status` *as of* each interval (day).

| as_of_date | event_id | reservation_status | sum_quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 100 | active | 4 |
| 2023-01-01 | 200 | active | 2 |
| 2023-01-02 | 100 | active | 11 |
| 2023-01-02 | 200 | active | 2 |
| 2023-01-03 | 100 | active | 20 |
| 2023-01-03 | 200 | active | 3 |
| 2023-01-04 | 100 | active | 20 |
| 2023-01-04 | 200 | active | 1 |
| 2023-01-04 | 200 | cancelled | 2 |
| 2023-01-06 | 100 | active | 23 |

<sup>*Rough estimate of row values. Will be different if using complete range of dates.*</sup>

I essentially want to do the following:

```sql
/* Invalid SQL, just for conceptual purposes */

-- Given a list of dates, for each "date":
select
  event_id,
  reservation_status,
  sum(quantity)
from table
where {{date}} between valid_from and valid_to
group by
  event_id,
  reservation_status
```

I believe this can be done using procedural language, such as a for loop, but I feel like I am overthinking that, and just having trouble combining simpler concepts.

Comment: add Calendar table with all your dates and join to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was very much overthinking it. Thank you to [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71647610/best-way-to-run-a-sql-query-for-different-dates) for reminding me of the basics, particularly that you can just join `on` `and` with comparisons, and SergeyA's comment: just make a list of dates and join to it.

Here is one complete solution ([db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iaQlvRFi)):

```sql
with

-- Generate range of days based on valid_from
-- Or use a calendar table/date dimension
all_dates as (
  select day::date
  from generate_series(
      (select min(valid_from) from Reservations),
      (select max(valid_from) from Reservations),
      '1 day'
  ) day
),

-- Quantities as of each day
quantity_as_of as (
  select
    day as as_of_date,
    Reservations.event_id,
    Reservations.reservation_status,
    sum(Reservations.quantity) as sum_quantity
  from all_dates as ad
  join Reservations
    on valid_from <= ad.day and ad.day < valid_to
  group by
    ad.day,
    Reservations.event_id,
    Reservations.reservation_status
  order by as_of_date, event_id
)
  
select * from quantity_as_of
```

| as_of_date | event_id | reservation_status | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 100 | active | 4 |
| 2023-01-01 | 200 | active | 2 |
| 2023-01-02 | 100 | active | 7 |
| 2023-01-02 | 200 | active | 3 |
| 2023-01-03 | 100 | active | 20 |
| 2023-01-03 | 200 | active | 1 |
| 2023-01-04 | 100 | active | 20 |
| 2023-01-04 | 200 | cancelled | 2 |
| 2023-01-04 | 200 | active | 1 |
| 2023-01-05 | 100 | active | 20 |
| 2023-01-05 | 200 | active | 1 |
| 2023-01-05 | 200 | cancelled | 2 |
| 2023-01-06 | 100 | active | 23 |
| 2023-01-06 | 200 | cancelled | 2 |
| 2023-01-06 | 200 | active | 1 |